# Scala: Try till first success on a list

Tags: scala, functional-programming, try-catch, scalaz, fold

What is the idiomatic way of applying a function `A => Try[B]` on a `List[A]` and return either the first succesful result `Some[B]` (it short-circuits) or if everything fails, returns `None`

I want to do something like this:

```
val inputs: List[String] = _

def foo[A, B](input: A): Try[B] = _

def main = {
  for {
   input <- inputs 
  } foo(input) match {
    case Failure(_) => // continue
    case Success(x) => return Some(x) //return the first success
  }
  return None   // everything failed
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the same thing using `collectFirst` in one less step:

```
inputs.iterator.map(foo).collectFirst { case Success(x) => x }
```

Comment: Related question. What if I wanted either first `Success[A]` or the last `Failure`?

Comment: @wrick: `val tmp = inputs.toStream.map(foo); tmp.find(_.isSuccess) orElse tmp.lastOption`

Answer (score 8):

You want this:

```
inputs
  .iterator // or view (anything lazy works)
  .map(foo)
  .find(_.isSuccess)
  .map(_.get)
```

It returns an `Option[B]`.

Comment: No, I want it to "short circuit" i.e. not evaluate after first success. `foo` in my case is expensive and slow and my list of inputs is large.

Comment: That's what the `.iterator` is for. It's also why I said anything lazy works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same thing but it will return the last `Failure` in the list if none are successful. Theoretically `tries.find(_.isSuccess).getOrElse(tries.last)` would work, but on a list view (lazy list) that causes all the attempts to be evaluated twice. Instead, this works for lazy lists (throws on empty collection):

```scala
val tries = inputs.view.map(foo)

val firstSuccessOrLastFailure = tries.zipWithIndex.collectFirst({
  case (s @ Success(_), _) => s
  case (f, i) if (i == tries.size - 1) => f
}).get
```